# How to DRY up VueJS + Vuelidate server side validation error code?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, vuelidate

I'm working on a VueJS project (using the Quasar framework). When building a form component, for example to edit user settings, I have frontend validation, to check required fields etc. using vuelidate, and I want to also show backend validation errors. Currently my setup (for a sample form) is as follows:

**script:**

```
export default {
  name: 'UserEditForm',
  mixins: [formServerValidation],
  data: function () {
    return {
      form: {
        ...
        name: this.$store.state.currentUser.attributes.name,
        currentPassword: 'winnerwinner',
        serverErrors: {
          // Todo: Autogenerate all server errors
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit () {
      const name = this.form.name
      const currentPassword = this.form.currentPassword
      this.clearServerErrors()


      this.$store.dispatch('updateUser', { name, currentPassword, }).then((result) => {
        console.log("Server update success")
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Server update error")
        const mappedErrors = this.mapServerErrors(err.response.data.errors)
        merge(this.form.serverErrors, mappedErrors)
        this.$refs.form.validate()
      })
    },
    serverError: function (fieldName) {
      return (value, vm) => {
        return !(
          Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(vm, 'serverErrors') &&
          Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(vm.serverErrors, fieldName)
        )
      }
    }
  },
  validation: {
    form: {
      ...
      name: {
        required,
        serverError: this.serverError('name')
      },
      currentPassword: {
        required,
        serverError: this.serverError('currentPassword')
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

**template:**

```
<template>
<q-form @submit="onSubmit" ref="form">
  ...
  <q-input
    field-name="name"
    type="text"
    v-model="form.name"
    label="Name"
    lazy-rules
    @input="clearServerError('name', $event)"
    :rules="[
      val => $v.form.name.required || 'Enter name',
      val => $v.form.name.serverError || form.serverErrors.name,
    ]" />

  <q-input
    field-name="currentPassword"
    type="password"
    v-model="form.currentPassword"
    label="Current password*"
    lazy-rules
    @input="clearServerError('currentPassword', $event)"
    :rules="[
      val => $v.form.currentPassword.required || 'Confirm password',
      val => $v.form.currentPassword.serverError || form.serverErrors.currentPassword
    ]"
    />
  ...
  <div>
    <q-btn label="Save" type="submit" color="primary" />
  </div>
</q-form>
</template>
```

This all works perfectly fine, however it seems to be very WET (not DRY). I have to define the following things for each field **manually**:

1. `serverError: this.serverError('name')` in `validation`
2. A rule `val => $v.form.name.serverError || form.serverErrors.name` in the template
3. `@input="clearServerError('name', $event)"` in the template

But I know I want to do this for **every** input in my form component, so it feels very repetitive to do this manually for every input component. Is there a correct "Vue-ish" way to DRY this up?

One thing I tried is to find all input fields by traversing all descendants of my form component using `$children`. Then:

I tried to tackle `1.`, by defining these server errors dynamically by looping over all input components.

`2.` is harder to tackle since you can not directly update the property `:rules` since Vue will override it on a new render of the parent component. (This also throws a warning, saying you should not directly update properties, but use `v-model` etc.)

I tried to tackle `3.` by defining input event listeners dynamically from my Form component using the `$on` method on the actual input components.

The DRY-up for 1 and 3 seem to work, but is it the best way of doing it? And what is a correct approach of drying up 2?

Comment: Recently, I came across an awesome concept of [object oriented forms](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/19) by Jeffrey Way. Please check it out.

Comment: Pretty nice resource indeed. It does not directly give a suggestions for add the :rules dynamically. However it is inspiring to give the responsibility of handling errors to a dedicated class.